# Как сделать выборку из БД с такой структурой?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как составить SQL запрос, чтобы взять order_id = 4 и поле value у shipping_id был равен 76? Именно у shipping_id, потому что число 76 может быть и в других записях value

Comment: ЯННП. Что является параметрами и какой нужен результат? Параметры - значения поля order_id и поля name, а получить надо значение поля value? Ну так простейший же ж запрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал выборку `order_id`, для которых есть записи, удовлетворяющие вашему критерию, проверку положил бы в подзапрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`order_id`) FROM `table` top WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
    WHERE top.`order_id` = `order_id`
    AND `name` = 'shipping_id'
    AND `value` = 76
)
```

Разумеется вы можете уточнить критерии, добавить еще проверки других полей и так далее. DISTINCT чистит запрос от повторяющихся `order_id`, `COUNT(*)` просто превращается в логическое выражение для WHERE